# The definition of $p$ capacity of a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, definition, geometric-measure-theory

I am having a bit of difficult understanding the definition of the $p$-capacity of a set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and I was wondering if anyone would be able to clarify whether I have the right idea or not.

This is what I understand so far. Formerly the definition of the $p$-capacity of a set is presented as follows.

Fix $1\leq p<n$. Define,
\begin{equation}
K^p\equiv\{f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ \vert\ f\geq 0, f\in L^{p^{\ast}}(\mathbb{R}^n), Df\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)\}.
\end{equation}
If $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ we define the quantity
\begin{equation}
\text{Cap}_p(A)    \equiv   \inf\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\vert Df\vert^p\text{ d}x\ \middle|\   f\in K^p, A\subset\text{int}\{f\geq 1\}\right\}
\end{equation}
as the $p$-capacity of $A$ (denoted by Cap$_p(A)$).

My thought process on this is as follows:

1. Pick an $f\in K^p$, and look at int$\{f\geq 1\}$.
2. At this point, we ask ourselves : is $A\subset\text{int}\{f\geq 1\}$? If not then repeat step 1.
3. Compute the quantity $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\vert Df\vert^p\text{ d}x$
4. Save it in a list $L$.
5. Repeat the process until all possible $f$ from $K^p$ have been considered.

Taking the 'smallest' number from the list $L$ defines the $p$-capacity of $A$. Is this a correct way to think about the definition of Cap$_p(A)$? I am aware of the distinction between minimum and infimum which is why I 've put 'smallest' in inverted commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you are right. However, thinking of a list might be misleading, since there are infinitely many functions in $K^p$.