# Show that the following $u\in L^{\infty}\cap H^1(B)$ is a weak solution to the given system.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

Let $B=B_{\exp(-2)}\subset\mathbb{R}^2$.

I would like to show that a weak solution to the following system (in $B$):
\begin{align*}
\triangle u_1&=-2|Du|^2(u_1+u_2)/(1+|u|^2)\\
\triangle u_2&=2|Du|^2(u_1-u_2)/(1+|u|^2)
\end{align*}
is
\begin{equation*}
u_1=\sin \big(\log (\log |x|^{-1})\big), \quad u_2=\cos \big(\log (\log |x|^{-1})\big).
\end{equation*}I have already shown that $u=(u_1, u_2)\in L^{\infty}(B)\cap H^1(B)$. Further, $u$ has certain second weak derivatives in $B$. Also, 
\begin{equation}
u\in L^{\infty}(B)\cap H^1(B)\cap C^{\infty}(B\setminus\{0\})
\end{equation}and $u$ satisfies the system outside the origin (I have shown this).

To show that it is a weak solution, I would like to show that for any $\phi\in L^{\infty}(B)\cap H^1(B)$ with compact support in $B$ I have

\begin{equation}
-\int_BDu_i\cdot D\phi\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_B \triangle u_i\phi\ \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}for each $i=1, 2$.

I started off by noting that if $\phi\in L^{\infty}(B)\cap H^1(B)$ with compact support in $B$, then $T\phi=0$ where $T$ is the trace operator, hence $\phi\in H_0^1(B)=\overline{C_c^{\infty}(B^0)}$. Consequently, there exists a sequence, $\{\phi_m\}_{m=1}^{\infty}\subset C_c^{\infty}(B^0),$ such that 
\begin{equation}
\|\phi_m-\phi\|_{H^1(B)}\rightarrow 0\quad(\text{as }m\rightarrow \infty).
\end{equation}This gives us
\begin{equation}
-\int_BDu_i\cdot D\phi_m\ \mathrm{d}x=\int_B \triangle u_i\phi_m\ \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}since $u_i$ has second weak derivatives (in those directions). Then
\begin{equation}
\|Du_i(D\phi_m-D\phi)\|_{L^1(B)}\leq\|Du\|_{L^2(B)}\|D\phi_m-D\phi\|_{L^2(B)}\rightarrow 0
\end{equation}as $m\rightarrow\infty$. Therefore, the left hand side converges to
\begin{equation}
-\int_BDu_i\cdot D\phi\ \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation} for each $i=1, 2$ and now I want to show that the right hand side converges to
\begin{equation}
\int_B\triangle u_i\phi\ \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}for each $i=1, 2$. This is where I am having some difficulty. I thought if I could show that the operator $L_i: H_0^1(B^0)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ defined for each $i=1, 2$ as
\begin{equation}
L_i\phi\equiv\int_B \triangle u_i\phi\ \mathrm{d}x,
\end{equation}is a bounded linear operator then by the density of $C_c^{\infty}(B^0)$ in $H_0^1(B)$ I would have $L_i\phi_m\rightarrow L_i\phi$, as desired. However, in trying to show that $L_i$ is bounded, I get as far as
\begin{equation}
\int_{B}|\triangle u_i||\phi_m-\phi|\ \mathrm{d}x\leq C\int_B|Du|^2|\phi_m-\phi|\ \mathrm{d}x
\end{equation}and then I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: As you have said, $u\in H^2$, hence the only thing you need to show is that $\Delta u$ satisfies yoour equation almost everywhere. Did you verified it?

Comment: I didn't say $u\in H^2$. It has second weak derivatives but I could not show that the second weak derivatives are in $L^2$. Outside the origin $u$ satisfies the system.

Comment: I see. I was using another definition for weak differentiable. Let me ask you one thing: Why do you think that $u$ is a weak solution of this problem? I am asking it, because $u$ is not even in $H^2$. $L_i$ is not even well defined in $H_0^1$, because $\Delta u_i$ does not belong to $L^2$, not even in $L^{1+\delta}$. It is only in $L^1$. If the dimension was $3$ then you could prove the continuity, because of the immersion $H_0^1(B)\subset L^\infty$.

Comment: This example is not due to me but to Jens Frehse in his 1973 paper "A Discontinuous Solution of a Mildly Nonlinear Elliptic System" in which he says it is easy to show that $u$ is a weak solution to the system. I was trying to show it as an exercise.

Comment: Here is the link to his paper: http://download.springer.com/static/pdf/765/art%253A10.1007%252FBF01214096.pdf?auth66=1379811120_ea96a163b55a0fef72df9010fef1f1b3&ext=.pdf

Comment: Well, we will have to work out his argument of capacity. Do you have any idea of what he is talking about?

Comment: I'm not sure what he means by capacity, I'm inclined to say that it is 2-capacity, but Capacity is only defined for p<n and in this case p=n=2. I had an earlier question on the definition of capacity and here is the link to that question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376928/the-definition-of-p-capacity-of-a-set-a-subset-mathbbrn

Comment: I think he might be using some sort of concentration-cancellation type argument...I'll have to investigate more on this...but I think you are right as concentration-cancellation uses p-capacity  to extract weak solutions when we don't have strong convergence in $L^p$ norm...Thanks...hopefully I'll be able to get there and then I'll post a solution thereafter.

Comment: I've found another definition of capacity, which does not have the restriction $p<n$. Do you have the book of Hainonen: Nonlinear Potential Theory of Degenerate Elliptic Equations?

Comment: Yes I can get it from the library. I'll have a look at it and I've also put a request for Frehse's 1982 paper on "capacity methods in the theory of partial differential equations". Thanks.

Comment: Ok, I've tried to get an argument going and I decided to post it as an answer. I have used variational p-capacity in my work.