# Intuitive question about the trace operator (Sobolev spaces)

Tags: sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega$ an open and bounded domain in $R^n$ . Let $u \in  W^{1,p} (\Omega) \cap L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ $(2 \leq p < \infty)$ . Let $B \subset \subset \Omega$ a open ball and consider $u_1$ the restriction of $u$ on $B$. Then we have $u_1 \in  W^{1,p} (B) \cap L^{\infty}(B)$. Let $T : W^{1,p} (B) \rightarrow L^{p}(\partial B) $ the trace operator. Can I say that $T(u_1) \in L^{\infty}(\partial B)$ ? Intuitively this is true .. But I dont know how to  proof or counter example... Someone can give me a help? I am not good with the trace operator...

thanks in advance

Comment: Please have a look here. It gonna helpful. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079409/the-essential-sup-over-the-boundary-vs-the-trace-of-a-sobolev-function

Comment: Why do you ask all of your questions using the word intuitive?

Comment: Hi Tomás . I write this when the affirmation seems to be true in simple cases (for example : smooth functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $\phi_n\in C^\infty(B)$ be a sequence satisfying: $\phi_n\to u_1$ in $W^{1,p}(B)$ and $\|\phi_n\|_\infty\le M$ for all $n$, where $M$ is a positive constant (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531054/can-u-in-w-01-p-cap-l-infty-be-approximated-by-a-sequence-u-k-in-c-0-inf)).

Note that $\phi_n\to u_1$ in $W^{1,p}(B)$, therefore, $(\phi_n-M)^+\to (u_1-M)^+$ in $W^{1,p}(B)$.

By one hand, $T((\phi_n-M)^+)=0$ for all $n$. On the other hand, once $(\phi_n-M)^+\to (u_1-M)^+$ in $W^{1,p}(B)$, we have that $T((\phi_n-M)^+)\to T((u_1-M)^+)$, thus $T((u_1-M)^+)=0$.

The last paragraph does implies that $$\inf\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}:\ T((u_1-\alpha)^+)=0\}<\infty.$$

To conclude, use this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1079409/the-essential-sup-over-the-boundary-vs-the-trace-of-a-sobolev-function).