# Can $u\in W^{1,\infty}\cap H^1(\mathbb R^n)$ be approximated by a sequence $u_k\in C_0^{\infty}(\mathbb R^n)$ with $\|u_k\|_{1,\infty}$ bounded?

Tags: analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces

This problem is relevant to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531054/can-u-in-w-01-p-cap-l-infty-be-approximated-by-a-sequence-u-k-in-c-0-inf) but I am not really able to prove it or find a counterexample. Could anyone give a hint?

Comment: Find evans book where he proves the approximation theorem. Then look at the construction of approximation functions, you will find how to prove your problem. If you can not do it, let me know and I will write you a answer.

Comment: @wisher Thanks for the tip, I think I have it now. I will write a full answer when I find some time.