What is p capacity of set actually saying?
Fix $1\leq p<n$. Define,
\begin{equation}
K^p\equiv\{f:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\ \vert\ f\geq 0, f\in L^{p^{\ast}}(\mathbb{R}^n), Df\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^n;\mathbb{R}^n)\}.
\end{equation}
If $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ we define the quantity
\begin{equation}
\text{Cap}_p(A)    \equiv   \inf\left\{\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\vert Df\vert^p\text{ d}x\ \middle|\   f\in K^p, A\subset\text{int}\{f\geq 1\}\right\}
\end{equation}
as the $p$-capacity of $A$ (denoted by Cap$_p(A)$).
Can someone break down what is this actually doing? I am not able to see what it is really calculating and implying. Can someone give me a much more detailed description on it? Since only the most abstract definitions are being given.

Small hint: what is the capacity of a bounded set?

Can you please clarify more

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/376928/the-definition-of-p-capacity-of-a-set-a-subset-mathbbrn

If $A$ is bounded, there exists a (bump-like) function that is a constant 1 on an open neighbourhood of $A$ and is $L^{p^*}$. What is $Df$ on $A$ then, and what is Cap_p(A) for any $p$?

“A Sobolev function in $ W^{1,p} $ can exhibit arbitrary behavior only on sets of p-capacity zero.” (See last point.) This has to be explained though: a Sobolev function can be arbitrarily changed on a set of measure zero and it is technically still the same function. However, recall the ACL characterization of Sobolev functions which says that a Sobolev function has a representative that is absolutely continuous on almost every line parallel to the axes. This shows immediately for example, that we cannot truly change the values of a Sobolev function as we wish on any solid line segment.
On the other hand, changing the value of a function at one single point, or even on countably many points does not violate absolute continuity on almost every line, since a.e. line does not contain any of those points.
So, the question becomes: on how large a set can a Sobolev function be “genuinely” discontinuous, in the sense that its precise representative is not continuous?
The p-capacity is the answer to that question.
A few remarks. 1) If p>n then Sobolev function has a continuous representative. Hence, even single points have positive p-capacity  Hence, a Sobolev function in $ W^{1,p} $ cannot obtain arbitrary values even at single points. This explains the restriction to $ p<n $.

The higher p value is, the more integrable the function’s derivative is. Hence we expect the set on which the function can exhibit arbitrary behavior to be smaller. That is why the bigger p is the smaller are the sets of p-capacity zero.

You can think of sets withp-capacity zero as having Hausdorff dimension no larger than $n-p$. Notice again the reverse relation with increase in p.

Another way of looking at it, not covered in Evans and Gariepy’s book, is that “if we have a compact set E of p-capacity zero, then every $W^{1,p}$ function on complement of E is the restriction of a (unique) $W^{1,p}$ function on all of R^n.



Forgot to add: The Lebesgue measure cannot distinguish between a set of p-capacity zero and a q-capacity zero. Both are not seen by it. So, p -capacity is a much refined way to distinguish aready small sets from one another. You must read between lines in Evans and Gariepy to see all of the claims above.
